# How do you programmatically reboot Ubuntu while logged in as a guest user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system

I want to write a script that reboots the computer while logged in as a guest user. I know this is possible because the guest user can shutdown from the settings button in the top right corner.

However, when I try run `reboot` from a script or terminal, I get `reboot: Need to be root`. I can't use `sudo` because the guest user doesn't have sudo access.

Why doesn't `reboot` work when the shutdown button is able to reboot the system as guest?

Comment: Why not? By definition if you're using the UI, you're almost always sitting at the console - what'd be the point of denying a proper shutdown path when they could just yank the power cord or poke the power button? Plus, the UI itself would be invoking the shutdown command with root privs in the background anyways.

Comment: Im not sure why it would be a big deal to type `sudo reboot`....

Comment: @ryekayo ofcourse the user is not in sudoers group ... but still the user can restart using the gear at top right corner (wonder)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. It would be a better fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @thatotherguy: I don't believe this is a valid edit. The question as you've edited it is valid and on-topic, but it's *not* the same thing the OP was asking (which was *why* a non-root user can reboot via the GUI but not using the `reboot` command). If you want to ask how to programmatically reboot Ubuntu, or if the OP wants to ask that, I suggest posting a new question. I'm all for improving questions, but not changing them to something completely (well, not quite completely) different.

Comment: @KeithThompson The way I saw it, the question was only off-topic because the user encountered the problem while writing a one-line program on a command line instead of in a text file. I think it's a perfectly reasonable thing to ask here, so I just added the implication that this might end up in a script. I re-edited to asked "why" instead of explicitly "how", and marked my answer as community so it doesn't look like I'm doing edits in favor of karma.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Hmm. I see your point, but I respectfully disagree. The OP wasn't asking about writing a script.

Comment: @KeithThompson You're right of course, but I feel that if `s/in a script//g` on an on-topic bash/ubuntu question is enough to make it off-topic, the distinction is not useful. It's still a question about why a statement in a programming language fails to do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @KeithThompson I asked this question here because I thought that I could get an answer from this forum. If you think otherwise be my guest to close. but that would prove that even though I could have received an answer from here I am supposed to put questions on similar forums. Even if I have to create account and understand that forum rules and to go through couple of days to see how things work on that place.

Comment: @thatotherguy I loved your edits +1

Comment: I already voted to close -- but if you're satisfied with the question in its current form I have no further complaints. I do think your question in its original form would have been a better fit for  http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login session is handled by `systemd-logind`, which runs as root and allows you to signal it to reboot. This is what the graphical reboot button does.

You [can signal it from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454039/what-command-is-executed-when-shutdown-from-the-graphical-menu-in-14-04) as well:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 \
         "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot" boolean:true
```

The `reboot` command tries to reboot the system on its own, without help from `systemd-logind`. It therefore fails because you're not able to give it root access.